# switch video tags or load new scource

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a question about performance on the video tag. 
Is it better to load a new video or to preload them in there own video tag and just disable the overlaying video tag.

The effect i want to achieve is seamless transition in to the next video who starts with the last frame frome the other video.

Could anyone tell me if there's a performace difference.

Thanks in advance,

Bastien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the next video to start immediately the previous finished then you will need to have started loading it in advance, to get the metadata and to populate the player buffer.

Doing this with two players or video tags as you describe is quite a common technique and will work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have tested it and it does indeed boost performance alot.